# Wrong balance after swap

Tags: erc-20, pancakeswap

It is probably more related to BSC than ETH but it was swapped from ETH though.

I made two transactions, one swap ETH for 15k Forever FOMO tokens (didn't check the wallet balance after).

Then second transaction 30k tokens.. so the balance should be 45k tokens in my wallet.

But my wallet is showing balance only 41k tokens, what the heck happened? Where is the rest?

[image]

https://bscscan.com/token/0x95637d4fbe7153dcc3e26e71bde7a2d82621f083?a=0x3247a5edb568820cea224dcd42379f760dcf1cf7

**EDIT:**

detail of one transaction, where seems to be some "middle man" transfer.

[image]

Comment: Don't buy into random scams to avoid issues like this.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa yes it was speculation but it might work

Answer (score 2):

Without really knowing the token, my guess is that this is caused by internal token fees.

It seems to be in fashion nowadays to have all sorts of internal fees for token transfers. So whenever you want to get 10 tokens, you may get, for example, 8 tokens and 2 tokens go to various fees. The usage for the fees also varies and it can be almost anything: liquidity pool, development funds, burn, ...

Comment: aha i thought that if the blokchain says you will get X tokens then you will get X tokens, but it is still somehow proccesed by the token logic itself?? that is quite strange?

Comment: but if you click the link and one of the transaction it is true that there is like some "middle man" like transfering A count of tokens from Pancake to some foreign wallet and then transfering B count of tokens to my wallet.

Comment: checkout my edited post

Comment: Token transfers are always processed by the token code itself. So there can really be anything - it may even give you back 0 tokens.

Comment: Hm interesting.

Comment: I noticed the balance is still decreasing so basically someone stole my tokens.. how it could happen? The token creator has access to my wallet? How can i trace what happened?

Comment: Sounds like a scam token. But, no, probably they don't have access to your wallet - just scam token with code which allows the creators/someone to steal that token

Comment: So how they decrease the tokens count in the wallet, is it some property of BSC smart chain, which ERC20 standard doesn't have i guess. But i didnt have even any priviledge to access my wallet etc. I was just using the Pancakeswap. But by reading the comments it happened also to other people. https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoMoonShots/comments/pvmnjg/comment/helvhnz/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3